# When is a WPF window usable as an Owner?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

We have an intermittent problem where an `InvalidOperationException` is being thrown in the `ShowDialog` method of a dialog window. The suspect cause is because the dialog is setting its `Owner` to a window which hasn't been displayed yet. This conclusion is based on the following:

1. The main application window (intended `Owner` of the dialog) instantiates and invokes `ShowDialog` on the dialog during its `Loaded` handler.
2. The dialog sets its `Owner` to the application window during its constructor
3. The documentation for `Window.Owner` says it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if set to a window that hasn't been displayed yet.
4. We assume the (main application window) `Loaded` event may be fired before the window is displayed.
5. The exception is usually not thrown because the main application window is shown by the time the `ShowDialog` call is made. When the host system is under stress, the application window "Show" may be delayed, so that when `ShowDialog` is called, it isn't yet ready to be used as an `Owner`.

The question is: is this true? If so, what window event or override can be used to reliably fire **after** it has been displayed, so that the window may then be reliably used as the dialog's `Owner`, regardless of system conditions?

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MyMainWindow"
   ... etc...
   Loaded="OnLoaded">
   ... etc...
</Window>

class MyMainWindow : Window
{
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new MyDialog(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        dialog.ShowWindow();
    }
}

class MyDialog: Window
{
    public MyDialog(Window window)
    {
        Owner = window;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: is this true?

Looks that way from inspecting the code.  *Programming WPF* by Chris Sells & Ian Griffiths also states that the `Loaded` event is raised just *before* the window is shown.

> What window event or override can be used to reliably fire after it has been displayed, so that the window may then be reliably used as the dialog's Owner, regardless of system conditions?

The `ContentRendered` event will be fired once, upon showing the window.  I think it would be the best choice for your situation.

You can also force a Window's hWnd to be created at any time, though I'm not sure that would be enough to avoid the exception, as a created window isn't necessarily 'shown'.  Still, it's a useful thing to know if you ever end up calling Win32 methods related to window management:

```
new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle()
```